# laravel eloquent query builder updating custom timestamp field without any logic

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-scheduler, eloquent

I have two columns in a table called `expired(boolean)` and `expire_date(timestamp)`. I m running a scheduler to check if a coupon is expired or not in `everyMinute()` while updating the `expired` column values using foreach, I have found that its changing the expired_date column value with todays date. I found this weird or may be I am messing up with the pass by reference thing.. here is the code

```
$schedule->call(function () {
            CoursePromotion::where('expired',0)
                ->whereDate('expire_date','<',Carbon::today())
                ->update(['expired' => 1]);
      })->everyMinute();
```

here is the result,

DB before updating

[image]

DB after running the `php artisan schedule:run` command

[image]

Can anyone tell me why the expired_date has been updated with todays date?

Comment: Use `Carbon::now()`, not `Carbon::today()`, the second one just return the date and not the actual time

Answer (score 2):

Check you database table(Having this '`expired_date`' column), not sure but issue with attribute for same column.
If you found attribute like '`on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`' for '`expired_date`' column then remove it and check.

[image]

Further this '`on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`' attribute will update date with current on while update action perform for particular record(s).